# When CSS cascading doesn't work

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have `#nav a {color:1}` selector, and few line below, another selector `a.current {color:2}` that specifies more properties on current a element (navigation bar and selected element/page). Thus, color from second selector doesn't work, color 1 remains on element.

If I put `#nav a.current {color:2}`, then it is working. Why so? It seems like selector with specified section id="nav" has some sort of precedence.

Comment: It does; it’s called [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alluded to in one of the comments, specificity is what's going on here. Going by [the official definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity), the `#nav a` selector has a specificity of 101 (assuming base 10), and `a.current` has a specificity of 10. The former has a high specificity, so it takes precedence.

`#nav a.current` has a specificity of 111.

Here's the [official specification of the cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#cascading) for reference.

Comment: Specificity is actually one of the many components of the cascade, so in reality the cascade is in full force. The cascade does not simply refer to the order of declarations in a single style rule, but style resolution as a whole.